# Model property casts empty array in Laravel when it shouldn't

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

everyone.
Model has a property

```
protected $casts = ['changes' => 'array'];
```

It's saved by laravel in db automatically as json object. For example

```
{"before":{"title":"Title1"},"after":{"title":"Title2"}}
```

But when I try to get it in a controller method as $this->changes it returns empty array `[]` for some reason. I created a getter:

```
    public function getTestAttribute()
    {
        return $this->changes;
    }
```

And that's what i get in tinker:

```
>>> $activity->changes
=> [
     "before" => [
       "creation_date" => "2021-05-12",
     ],
     "after" => [
       "creation_date" => "2020-07-07 00:00:00",
     ],
   ]
>>> $activity->test
=> []
```

And the same thing happens in a method where I reference the property. Undefined index because it's an empty array

```
$before = $this->changes['before'];

PHP Notice:  Undefined index: before
```

I have no idea what's going on and why it's empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$changes` is a variable that the Model already defines, which is where it keeps the changes to the attributes to know if the model is dirty. This is `protected`. When you are outside the model it is not an accessible property so `__get` is called which will call `getAttribute`. When you are inside the model `$changes` is accessible so you get the actual property named `changes`, which is an empty array `[]` at that moment.

Comment: Finally I just referenced the property in controller. Not in model and it works. But if I wanted to work with it inside model in toArray() method to pass it through API should I change the property name? @lagbox Thank you

Comment: `toArray` uses the attributes, it doesn't have to do with the properties, inside the model you can access the `$attributes` array, or deal with `getAttribute` as options